# My blender render view ports are slow in material mode, but I don't know the reason

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view

I am working on a project for a level map for a small lowpoly city. I have 143 materials and I used 111 materials from them, but the problem is that my view port is very slow. The program only uses about 65% of my RAM and less than 50% of the CPU power. All of my textures are 1500px * 1500px  and all of my materials are shadeless. I don't use any lights and I have only 5000 faces on this layer.

What could be the reason? Are the problems from Blender or from my PC? Can I do this task in blender or do I need a different software?

[image: screenshot of task manager showing CPU, memory and network usage]

Comment: 143 materials is a lot. DO they all have image based textures?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yes they all have images

Comment: Well that is probably the reason, combined with the fact that Blender's viewport is inherently low performance

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos so are there any good software i can use in this task ?